# selecting row with multi index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have following DB, how i can select a row by retailer_name, visit_number, visit_date ?

```
category_name                                                     Blades & Razors & Foam  Diaper
    retailer_name store_number visit_date                                         
    ABest         1177         2016-03-01 06:10:49                      86     191
                               2016-03-24 08:59:33                     129     222
                               2016-03-29 04:34:36                     114     323
                               2016-04-12 10:56:26                     225     235
                  1182         2016-03-02 08:54:00                     161     217
```

For example I want to get  row for `'ABest'`, `1182`, `2016-03-02 08:54:00`

Thanks

Comment: Should you really use pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `slicers` - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Blades & Razors & Foam': {('ABest', 1177, pd.Timestamp('2016-03-01 06:10:49')): 86, ('ABest', 1177, pd.Timestamp('2016-03-29 04:34:36')): 114, ('ABest', 1177, pd.Timestamp('2016-03-24 08:59:33')): 129, ('ABest', 1177, pd.Timestamp('2016-04-12 10:56:26')): 225, ('ABest', 1182, pd.Timestamp('2016-03-02 08:54:00')): 161}, 'Diaper': {('ABest', 1177, pd.Timestamp('2016-03-01 06:10:49')): 191, ('ABest', 1177, pd.Timestamp('2016-03-29 04:34:36')): 323, ('ABest', 1177, pd.Timestamp('2016-03-24 08:59:33')): 222, ('ABest', 1177, pd.Timestamp('2016-04-12 10:56:26')): 235, ('ABest', 1182, pd.Timestamp('2016-03-02 08:54:00')): 217}})
df.columns.names=[u'category_name'] 
df.index.names=[u'retailer_name', u'store_number', u'visit_date'] 
print (df)
category_name                                   Blades & Razors & Foam  Diaper
retailer_name store_number visit_date                                         
ABest         1177         2016-03-01 06:10:49                      86     191
                           2016-03-24 08:59:33                     129     222
                           2016-03-29 04:34:36                     114     323
                           2016-04-12 10:56:26                     225     235
              1182         2016-03-02 08:54:00                     161     217

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['ABest',1182,'2016-03-02 08:54:00'],:])
category_name                                   Blades & Razors & Foam  Diaper
retailer_name store_number visit_date                                         
ABest         1182         2016-03-02 08:54:00                     161     217
```

EDIT:

If you need change level `visit_date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), you can use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Blades & Razors & Foam': {('ABest', 1182, '2016-03-02 08:54:00'): 161, ('ABest', 1177, '2016-04-12 10:56:26'): 225, ('ABest', 1177, '2016-03-01 06:10:49'): 86, ('ABest', 1177, '2016-03-24 08:59:33'): 129, ('ABest', 1177, '2016-03-29 04:34:36'): 114}, 'Diaper': {('ABest', 1182, '2016-03-02 08:54:00'): 217, ('ABest', 1177, '2016-04-12 10:56:26'): 235, ('ABest', 1177, '2016-03-01 06:10:49'): 191, ('ABest', 1177, '2016-03-24 08:59:33'): 222, ('ABest', 1177, '2016-03-29 04:34:36'): 323}})
df.index.names=[u'retailer_name', u'store_number', u'visit_date'] 
print (df)
                                                Blades & Razors & Foam  Diaper
retailer_name store_number visit_date                                         
ABest         1177         2016-03-01 06:10:49                      86     191
                           2016-03-24 08:59:33                     129     222
                           2016-03-29 04:34:36                     114     323
                           2016-04-12 10:56:26                     225     235
              1182         2016-03-02 08:54:00                     161     217

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['visit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['visit_date'])
df.set_index(['retailer_name','store_number','visit_date'], inplace=True)


idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['ABest',1182,'2016-03-02 08:54:00'],:])
                                                Blades & Razors & Foam  Diaper
retailer_name store_number visit_date                                         
ABest         1182         2016-03-02 08:54:00                     161     217
```

Comment: I am getting KeyError: ('ABest', 1182, Timestamp('2016-03-02 08:54:00'))

Comment: Hmmm, I have no datetimeindex, please give me a sec.

Comment: Interesting, for me it works nice. What is your pandas version? `print pd.__version__`

Comment: But with real data is problem?

Comment: Btw, for me also works `print (df.loc[('ABest', 1182, '2016-03-02 08:54:00'),:])`, but I dont know if it is best practices solution.

Comment: I found the issue, please see the edit. how I can I remove that  category_name  from there ?

Comment: What is `df.index`?

Comment: names=[u'retailer_name', u'store_number', u'visit_date']

Comment: And `category_name` is df.columns.names ?

Comment: FrozenList([u'category_name'])

Comment: I try edit answer with this info, but it works nice.

Comment: I found the difference I have  pd.to_datetime, could you change your code to  pd.to_datetime, I get error when I try to use pd.Timestamp

Comment: Ok, you need convert level `visit_date` to `datetime`?

Comment: Thanks for help. The issue was the data types. what I thought as int was actually string. After casting everything worked